# How to install a non python software inside python virtual environment?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, python-venv

I am trying to build and install FFmpeg inside a python virtual environment but I am stuck at `make install`

Every time I run `make install` I get an error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/share/doc’: Permission denied
```

Why is it taking global path instead of local virtual environment path?

Comment: It depends what you mean by a virtual environment -- in a docker dev container it's all isolated, in a traditional venv or conda env only the python instillation and packages are in their own environment - so you wouldn't actually install other things into those directories, you'd install them locally and reference their paths by code.

If you're familiar with docker I'd 100% recommend docker dev containers (in vs-code) that's more of a custom container for each project

Comment: @Schalton Thankyou for your comment, I am not very much familiar with docker so, Can you please tell me if i can run a command-line script in a docker environment like we do in venv without starting and stopping the container again and again?

Comment: Yes you can -- (this isn't technically correct), but you can think of docker as its own virtual machine

Comment: I'd give it a shot -- download docker, vs-code and install the extension docker-containers: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers

Comment: But to more directly answer your question -- you don't strictly need to install FFMpeg in the same directory as your python venv (you probably can with elevated permissions / `sudo` but I wouldn't). If this is production code docker has the nice added benefit of being easy to deploy to cloud infra